# Repeat Android code every 'X' minutes

Tags: java, android

I know this question was already made like 10 times here but I keep having problems to solve it, as I'm very newbie with Android.

I was bored and I had the idea of making an app for printing a list with last TeamSpeak3 connections of my clan server. The "server-side" job is already done, as I made a Java program that prints last connections in a TXT file ([ingenium.zapto.org/joins.txt](http://ingenium.zapto.org/joins.txt)). Now, I just want to make an Android app to print the content of that TXT file every 'X' minutes, for example, each 10.

I already have the code to access the TXT file and print it, but I'm not being able to make it re-print the list every 10 minutes.
I know there are tools like AlarmManager, Handlers, Timers... but I'm very confussed, I don't know what is the best one to use in this case and, more important, I don't know how to make them work in my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package org.zapto.ingenium.fetchurl;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView txtJoins;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtJoins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtJoins);

    FetchURL fu = new FetchURL();

    fu.Run("http://192.168.0.10/joins.txt");

    String o = fu.getOutput();

    txtJoins.setText("Last connections: \n" + o);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**FetchURL.java**

```
package org.zapto.ingenium.fetchurl;

/**
 * Created by Martin on 18/01/2015.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class FetchURL {

private String output;
private String url;

public FetchURL()
{
    output = "";
}

public String getOutput()
{
    return output;
}


public void Run(String u)
{
    url = u;
    Thread t =  new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            URL textUrl;
            try {

                textUrl = new URL(url);

                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

                String StringBuffer;
                String stringText = "";
                while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringText += "\n" + StringBuffer;
                }
                bufferReader.close();

                output = stringText;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();

                output= e.toString();
            }

        }
    };

    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LytContenedorSaludo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/TxtJoins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In summary, I want to repeat this 3 lines of code (MainActivity.java):

```
    fu.Run("http://192.168.0.10/joins.txt");

    String o = fu.getOutput();

    txtJoins.setText("Last conections: \n" + o);
```

every 10 minutes, for example.

Comment: So, since you know this has been asked dozens of time already, what have you tried and what was the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Thread` and have it repeat this task every 10 minutes. Something like the following would work. First declare the new `Thread`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView txtJoins;
private Thread repeatTaskThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Rest of code...
```

Then create a simple method which contains your new `Thread`:

```
private void RepeatTask()
{
    repeatTaskThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                FetchURL fu = new FetchURL();
                fu.Run("http://192.168.0.10/joins.txt");
                String o = fu.getOutput();
                // Update TextView in runOnUiThread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        txtJoins.setText("Last connections: \n" + o);
                    }
                });
                try
                {
                    // Sleep for 10 minutes
                    Thread.sleep(600000)
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    };
    repeatTaskThread.start();
}
```

And lastly, call your method at the end of `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Rest of code...

    RepeatTask();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your worked reply. Updating my code with this Thread method gives me an error: First, program executes, but after 10 minutes, program crashes and gives this error:
[link](http://pastebin.com/TEKJs30b)
Also, I got a question: This code only executes if the app is opened, right? I mean, is there any way to do this re-write each 10 minutes with having the app installed (but not necessarily opened)?. For example, for throwing a notification if the program detects if a new user is connected after this recheck.
Thank you!

Comment: Whoops, that was my fault. Changing the text for your `TextView` involves manipulating the UI, so it must be done in the UI Thread. I have updated my answer...

Comment: Also, to answer your second question... Yes, this will only work if the app is opened. If you want to continue running the above commands even if the application is closed or in the background, you should consider using a `Service`. I have attached both the overview and the API guide for your convenience: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Just to clarify, you CAN use a service to do this in the background but the app will have to been at least once at that point (referring to when you said installed but not necessarily opened).

Answer (score 1):

After completing your code use a Handler which will execute this all again after 10 minutes?

```
handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      // do something             
  }}, 600000);
```

//1000 = 1 sec // 60000 = 60 sec(1 minute) // 600000 = 600 sec (10 minutes)

Comment: Keep in mind, you cannot use a Handler to delay or loop code inside a service. It works in an activity or fragment. Instead use AlarmManager for a service.

Answer (score 0):

10min in 10min run the instruction 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
        fu.Run("http://192.168.0.10/joins.txt");
        String o = fu.getOutput();
        txtJoins.setText("Last conections: \n" + o);
        .start();
     }
  }.start();
```