# Android Studio Error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, handler, runtimeexception

I am trying to run a section of code every X seconds in an AsyncTask Activity and it is crashing before getting into any print statements. I am not sure why it is crashing, but I also posted the error I am getting. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much!

```
public class AppListener extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {


    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            try {

                String msg_received = null;

                System.out.println("LISTENING FOR LAST INSTALLED APP");


                System.out.println("TRY");

                Socket socket = new Socket("85.190.178.23", 5050);

                // Get data sent through socket
                DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

                // read data that got sent
                msg_received = DIS.readUTF();

                System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

                // Might not want to close socket, or only the first string will be sent and none after
                socket.close();


            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Did not receive string");
            }




            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);



    String msg_received = null;
    return msg_received;


}

}
```

MY ERROR

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

**Here is how I got my loop to execute every X seconds without interfering with my GUI if it is helpful to anyone else: instead of having a separate class, I just posted my code in my main activity right when my app starts**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{



private Thread repeatTaskThread;


// called when the activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


  // Go into loop that is repeated every X seconds
  RepeatTask();
}




private void RepeatTask()
{
  repeatTaskThread = new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
        while (true)
        {

         //Post your code here that you want repeated every X seconds
         // My "try" and "catch" statements from above got inserted here


           try
           {
              // Sleep for 5 seconds
              Thread.sleep(5000);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     };
  };
  repeatTaskThread.start();

}
}
```

Comment: I resolved my issue using this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028954/repeat-android-code-every-x-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Updated: When you're launching AsyncTasks doInBackground, you're launching a background thread. If you want to post AsyncTask's doInBackground with a delay, then you should not use an AsyncTask at all. You should only need to use a Handler with postDelayed, which will create a background thread for you. It looks like in your code, you tried launch a new Thread with a Handler *while* in AsyncTask's background thread.

Get rid of the AsyncTask altogether, and include this code in your Activity:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {


        try {

            String msg_received = null;

            System.out.println("LISTENING FOR LAST INSTALLED APP");


            System.out.println("TRY");

            Socket socket = new Socket("85.190.178.23", 5050);

            // Get data sent through socket
            DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

            // read data that got sent
            msg_received = DIS.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

            // Might not want to close socket, or only the first string will be sent and none after
            socket.close();


        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Did not receive string");
        }




        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);



String msg_received = null;
return msg_received;


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! If my class does not extend AsyncTask, then what should it extend? and What would my complete code for that class look like? For example would I put the Handler code that you have posted in an onCreate method? Also, this is not the main class for my project, by I want this class to start right when my app opens without interfering with my normal app GUI. Should I call it somehow from my main class? Thanks for all the help!